# I am using weblogic 12c when i am going to start server i am getting "unable to get file lock, will retry" is the weblogic

Tags: weblogic12c

I am using weblogic 12c
when i am going to start server i am getting  "unable to get file lock, will retry" is the weblogic 10.3.5/10.3.6 admin server log while trying to start a weblogic or managed server

Answer (score 14):

1. AdminServer.lok file using in jvm so first stop java.exe from task manager
2. Remove the AdminServer.lok or ManagedServer.lok file in the Oracle Middleware home $MW_HOME/user_projects/domains/servers/”Server name you are trying to start”/tmp directory.

Comment: Thanks.Worked for me.Remember to kill java.exe from taskmanager.

Comment: Worked for me, too!

Comment: Thanks it also solved my problem, I'm using web logic 12c!

Comment: Hi, For me my admin server is running fine. When I am re starting the managed server , I am getitng error. But the Manged Server Folder is empty. So cant remove these lok files. Tried killing admin server and removing lok file of admin server. Still Admin server is getting re started , But managed server giving same problem. Checked if manged server port is used by this command netstat -an | grep <Managed_Server_Port>. Its not running. I am not getting where exactly is the issue.